# Able to select dates beyond Min/max date on primeng calendar

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng

I am using the calendar from the angular primeng package to pick dates
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar

I need to set both a min/max date to prevent selecting before/after.
Below is how i do this.

```
this.calendarConfig.minDate = new Date(1567695600)
this.calendarConfig.maxDate = new Date(1568012400);
```

```
  <p-calendar
      dateFormat="dd/mm/yy"
      [(ngModel)]="calendarConfig.selectedDate"
      [minDate]="calendarConfig.minDate"
      [maxDate]="calendarConfig.maxDate"
      (onSelect)="loadCalendarDate()"
      showTime="true"
      [stepMinute]="0"
      [stepHour]="1"
      hourFormat="24"></p-calendar>
```

This works however I am able to go past the min/max date when using the time picker.

Steps:

1) Go to the min date on the calendar

2) Keep incrementing the time by 1 hour

3) You will hit midnight which is before the min date and the time buttons completely lock up.

This can also be done on the max date except you decrement the hour untill you hit 23:00 (which is greater than the maxDate)

I am using version 8.0.3.

Is there a solution to this or is it a bug.

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/8126

Comment: Also my issue ;)

Comment: Right! Just adding it here for an FYI.